# Make Javascript editable in Sitecore SXA CMS?

Tags: sxa, javascript

I am using `Rich Text Editor` for the template field for script content, I need to make the entire script editable in `Sitecore SXA 10`. The `RTE` removes the script content.

The script content is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/consent/{{ID}}-test/OtAutoBlock.js" >
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.cookielaw.org/scripttemplates/otSDKStub.js"  type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" data-domain-script="{{ID}}-test" >
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function OptanonWrapper() { }
</script>
```

Are there any alternative ways in Sitecore to consider the script content the way it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very short answer, but with a Rich Text field this will not work (you can tweak the RTE to allow all kinds of tags but you really don't want to do that for scripts).

Try using a `Multiline Text field`.  That should do it.

Comment: I tried using the Multiline text field but it doesn't work very well.

Comment: What is not working? Can you edit your question and clarify because you were mentioning the RTE...

Comment: Sorry @Gatogordo my bad. Thank you for your response. This helps.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you want to render custom scripts like this, then you can prefer the OOTB control in `SXA` to do this, called `Plain HTML` or `Plain HTML (Reusable)`

[image]

When you select this in `Experience editor` and click on `Edit HTML` button, it will open this in content editor mode and you will be able to add your custom `HTML` of `JS` in the field that is the type of `Multiline Text Field` as @Gatogordo mentioned in his answer.

[image]

And the HTML or JS will get rendered on your page.

Thanks